# Return object with specific attributes

Tags: javascript, object

lets say i have an array of objects

```
var x = [{
   a:'asd',
     b:'ss'
},{
   a:'s',
     b:'f',
     c:'asd'
},{
  a:'tt',
    g:'f',
    b:'ulaN'
}];
```

and i want to return array of objects , with objects only having `a` and `b` attributes.

I solved this with

```
x = x.map( y => {
   return {
     a:y.a,
     b:y.b
     }
});
```

but it seems not quite efficent in my opinion , is there any better way how to do so?

Comment: why is that inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly shorten this code by doing:

```
x = x.map( y => ({
  a: y.a,
  b: y.b
}));
```

Comment: By...removing a new line and a `return` statement. I don't really see how that answers the question. On the other hand, I'm not entirely sure what answer the question asks as it's really vague and broad at best.

Comment: Agree, it's not any more efficient from a code performance perspective. It's just less verbose. I don't think that the code can easily be made more efficient from a performance perspective, because no matter what you do it will be `O(n)`, which cannot be improved to my knowledge. Since each array item is an object (hashmap), lookups on individual keys is `O(1)`, and there are `n` items, meaning `O(n)`. It will be impossible to improve this, because reading a large array from memory takes `O(n)` time already.

Comment: Yeah. The code could be less verbose, yet my point is, I don't think this deserved a separate answer. And the performance stuff is also correct. Unless OP can specify _what_ is inefficient and why it needs to be improved, I don't think this is something that _can_ be answered. Currently best case scenario is a minor microptimisation that doesn't matter.